# Fast publication date lookup with Wikidata Query Service

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

Is there a way to lookup publication dates quickly in Wikidata Query Service's SPARQL to find publications of a certain date, e.g., today?

I was hoping that something like this query would be quick:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?work wdt:P577 ?datetime .
  BIND("2018-09-28T00:00:00Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> as ?now_datetime)
  FILTER (?datetime = ?now_datetime)
}
LIMIT 10
```

However, it times out when using it on the SPARQL endpoint at https://query.wikidata.org

A range query seems neither to be quick. The query below returns after almost 30 seconds:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
  ?work wdt:P577 ?datetime .
  FILTER (?datetime > "2018-09-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)
}
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick is to avoid full scan and use indexes:

1. [`VALUES`](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data):

   ```sql
   SELECT * WHERE {
     VALUES (?datetime) {("2018-09-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)}
     ?work wdt:P577 ?datetime .
   } LIMIT 10
   ```

   [Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fdatetime%29%20%7B%28%222018-09-28T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fwork%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fdatetime%20.%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010)
2. [`hint:rangeSafe`](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/QueryHints):

   ```sql
   SELECT * WHERE {
     VALUES (?datetime) {("2018-09-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime)}
     ?work wdt:P577 ?date_time .
     hint:Prior hint:rangeSafe true .
     FILTER (?date_time > ?datetime)
   } LIMIT 10
   ```

   [Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fdatetime%29%20%7B%28%222018-09-28T00%3A00%3A00Z%22%5E%5Exsd%3AdateTime%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fwork%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fdate_time%20.%0A%20%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArangeSafe%20true%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20%28%3Fdate_time%20%3E%20%3Fdatetime%29%0A%7D%20LIMIT%2010)

   > [The `rangeSafe` hint] declare[s] that the data touched by the query for a specific triple pattern is strongly typed, thus allowing a range filter to be pushed down onto an index.

Comment: why is `VALUES` necessary for a single literal lookup and not just `SELECT * WHERE {
 
  ?work wdt:P577 "2018-09-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime .
} LIMIT 10` ?

Comment: @AKSW, obviously, it's OK too. I consider `"2018-09-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime` as a kind of "inline data", for which `VALUES` is designed.